# WCF REST 400 bad request on POST WebInvoke

Tags: c#, json, post, webinvoke

So I have the following service:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getStuff?stuff={stuff}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    List<Row> getdTable(string stuff);
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/log", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST")]
    void insertLog(Log[] log);
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/testPost", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST")]
    void testPost(TwoStrings testPost);
}

[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]


[DataContract]
public class TwoStrings
{
    [DataMember]
    public string one { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string two { get; set; }
}
```

The WebGet works like a charm, but I can't get any of the webinvoke methods to actually work.
I'm testing it using fiddler right now, using the following POST:

```
POST http://localhost:50051/Service1.svc/testPost HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:50051  
User-Agent: Fiddler   
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
Content-Length: 25  
{"testPost":{"one":"test1","two":"test2"}}
```

And the response I get back is:

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I'm at a loss here, I've tried several different formats on the JSON body to no avail.
Is the JSON properly formatted? Is there any configuration required to do a POST?

edit: Solution found, I'm an IDIOT. The last time I corrected the fiddler request to reflect the proper body wrapping I forgot to alter the body size from 25 to the correct 38.
Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: try specifying the `datatype` like this: `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @CodeCaster I was under the impression the wrapped object was done based on the parameter name. How do I enable that btw?

Comment: @saravanan Where do I specify the dataType?

Comment: You can specify it in the ajax request like this `
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:50051/Service1.svc/testPost',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {"testPost":{"one":"test1","two":"test2"}},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                response.val(data.d);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                //TODO: do something here
            }
        });

`

Comment: I wasn't posting it using ajax yet, but that's cool to know. Should have mentioned I was using fiddler to compose the request.

Comment: What was the "proper body wrapping"?